# shadow dom style not showing

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom

A web component instantiated via this does not style correctly:

```
connectedCallback() {
  const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
  this.svg = document.createElement('svg');
  this.svg.style = `
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: beige;
  `;
  shadowRoot.appendChild(this.svg);
}
```

However, the style attribute shows the correct data in Chrome DevTools. If I rewrite the logic this way, the styling shows up.

```
connectedCallback() {
  const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
  let htmlHolder = document.createElement('template');
  htmlHolder.innerHTML = `<svg></svg>`;
  shadowRoot.appendChild(htmlHolder.content.cloneNode(true));
  this.svg = shadowRoot.querySelector('svg');
  this.svg.style = `
      height: 80px;
      width: 80px;
      background-color: beige;
  `;
}
```

I'm not sure why these 2 are behaving differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a SVG element with `createElement`, you should set the specific SVG namespace which is `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`.

You must then use [`createElementNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) method:

```
this.svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
```